# Extract polyline from Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following [map with a polyline between two points](http://winnipegtransit.com/en/navigo/result?leave_right_away=off&time=14%3A00&ampm=pm&timeMode=Depart_After&tripDate=4&originKey=11105&originName=St+Vital+Centre+%281225+St+Mary%27s+Road%29&originType=monument&destinationKey=8478&destinationName=Polo+Park+Shopping+Centre+%281485+Portage+Avenue%29&destinationType=monument&commit=Submit&waitingTime=20&minWaitingTime=0&maxWalkTime=20&walkingSpeed=4).

[image]

I would like to extract this polyline so that I can recreate it in a native Google Maps fragment on Android. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you want driving direction between two points?

Comment: I'm trying to extract the data structure which created this polyline above.